# Rebase is making push impossible

Tags: git, rebase

I'm having some trouble with Git using rebase, here is a "draw" of what the situation was, what I want and what I did.

```
Repo state (initial)

   --- C1 --- C5 --- C6 --- C7 (master & origin/master)
        \
         \--- C2 --- C3 --- C4 (my-branch & origin/my-branch)
```

```
Repo state (wanted)

   --- C1 --- C5 --- C6 --- C7 --- C2 --- C3 --- C4 (my-branch & origin/my-branch)
                             |
                (master & origin/master)
```

So, in this situation, I did this :

```
$ git checkout my-branch
$ git rebase origin/master
```

But the repo became in this state :

```
   --- C1 --- C5 --- C6 --- C7 --- C2 --- C3 --- C4 (my-branch)
        \                    |
         \       (master & origin/master)
          \
           \--- C2 --- C3 --- C4 (origin/my-branch)
```

So, when I tried to push "my-branch", git throw me an error telling me that my-branch had some not pulled changed so I could not push.

What I did (I know this is a **bad** solution) :

```
$ git push origin --delete my-branch
$ git push
```

So, the remote branch is deleted and newly created.

I am SURE there is an other solution, but I can't find what I did wrong in my thinking.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Use the `--force`, Luke!

Comment: Don't use `--force` unless you're working completely alone in that branch, or in a small team where people don't **pull** that branch frequently, otherwise you'll break everyone's repository. **Do not rebase if you're not alone, ever** (prefer [git-merge](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)) -  if you did it but want to avoid breaking everyone's repository, don't push it - instead create a new branch from that one and push the new branch.

Comment: We do not want to merge because master does not need the "my-branch" work now, but "my-branch" needs to be up-to-date with master

Comment: You can merge `master ` into `my-branch` using git-merge: `git checkout my-branch && git merge master`.

Comment: It does not solve the problem that I do not want the two branch to be merged, I just want `my-branch` to have `master` changes and `master` must not get `my-branch` changes.

Comment: git-merge brings changes from the specified branch to the current branch. So if you perform the previously mentioned commands, you'll get exaxtly what you just described. If you're in doubt, please, backup your current repo directory and then give it a try. If something doesn't work as you expect, just restore it.

Comment: I just tried, you were right. Please, create a post, so I can mark your answer as accepted. It seems that I didn't understand `git merge` as much as I was thinking. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future you can simply use  [git-merge](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge):

> git-merge - Join two or more development histories together
>
> Incorporates changes from the named commits (since the
>   time their histories diverged from the current branch) into the
>   current branch. This command is used by git pull to incorporate
>   changes from another repository and **can be used by hand to merge
>   changes from one branch into another**.

For example:

```
git checkout my-branch
git merge master
```

This will bring commits from `master` into `my-branch` without changing anything in `master`.

An extremely useful hint is learning how to use [git-reflog](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) and [git-reset](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) to undo an undesired rebase you might have already executed. Since you have already deleted the remote repo, it doesn't make sense to do this, but here's an example if you ever need it again:

```
git reflog
# This will print a history of repository changes.
# Pick the latest ref before the rebase - let's suppose it's HEAD@{3}

# CAUTION: Be sure you understand what git-reset --hard does
git reset --hard HEAD@{3}
```

Now your repository should be back to the state it was before you did the rebase.

NOTE - Regarding the `--hard` flag used with [git-reset](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset):

> --hard Resets the index and working tree. **Any changes to tracked files in the working tree since <commit> are discarded**.